# Select text of QLineEdit on focus

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qlineedit

I have created a dialog using QtDesigner. There is a `QLineEdit` object in the dialog with some default content. When the dialog initializes and the focus goes to the `QLineEdit`, I want the default content to be auto selected, so once the user start writing, the previous content will be overwritten.

***EDIT:***

In constructor:

```
dialog->accept();
```

and

```
connect( dialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), QlineObj, SLOT( selectAll() ) );
```

Comment: It is simply a bug. If I do a ui->myedwidget->deselect(); AFTER I have written something in the QLineEdit, it should remove any selection. But it is still there --> BUG. Unfortunately QT is filled with bugs. Because of these, I had to avoid QTableView and use instead QTableWidget. And this is just an example.
I am using QT 5.9.5 with QT Creator 4.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: It is simply a bug. If I do a ui->myedwidget->deselect(); AFTER I have written something in the QLineEdit, it should remove any selection. But it is still there --> BUG. Unfortunately QT is filled with bugs. Because of these, I had to avoid QTableView and use instead QTableWidget. And this is just an example.
I am using QT 5.9.5 with QT Creator 4.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 13):

Create a class derived from `QLineEdit` and override the `focusInEvent` in the header:

```c++
void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event) override;
```

Then implement it like so:

```c++
void MyLineEdit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    // First let the base class process the event
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);
    // Then select the text by a single shot timer, so that everything will
    // be processed before (calling selectAll() directly won't work)
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, &QLineEdit::selectAll);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Call

```
lineEdit->selectAll();
```

after you set the default text. (In the dialog constructor, perhaps.)

Comment: Thanks I already did it ;)
dialog->accept(); { in constructor }

and
connect( dialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), QlineObj, SLOT( selectAll() ) );

Comment: This works in constructor: QTimer::singleShot(0, lineEdit, SLOT(selectAll()));

Answer (score 8):

There is a simpler method to get almost the same behaviour, which is to set the default content using setPlaceholderText() instead of setText(). This will show the default content grayed out and as soon as the QLineEdit gains focus, it will disappear.

Comment: Drawback: This way you can't edit the default value, just replace it completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QApplication::focusChanged` along with `QTimer::singleShot` to select all the text on a changed focus.

Normally your `QApplication` is declared in main, so use `QObject::connect` there, eg:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    My_Main_Window w();
    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(focusChanged(QWidget*, QWidget*)),
                     &w, SLOT(my_focus_changed_slot(QWidget*, QWidget*)));
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Remember to make the public slot in the `My_Main_Window` class:

```
public slots:
void my_focus_changed_slot(QWidget*, QWidget*);
```

Then in your definition of `my_focus_changed_slot`, check if the second `QWidget*` (which points to the newly focused widget) is the same as the `QLineEdit` you wish to select all of, and do so using `QTimer::singleShot` so that the event loop gets called, then the `QLineEdit` has the `selectAll` slot called immediately after, eg

```
void My_Main_Window::focus_changed(QWidget*, QWidget* new_widget) {
    if (new_widget == my_lineedit) {
        QTimer::singleShot(0, my_lineedit, &QLineEdit::selectAll);
    }
}
```

where `my_lineedit` is a pointer to a `QLineEdit` and is part of the `My_Main_Window` class.

Comment: Can you please explain more why we needed to use `QTimer::singleShot`?

Comment: In qt documentation, it mentions QTimer::singleShot(). Basically it has to do with the event loop. Passing in 0 like I do in my example simply let's the event loop pass, then it notices the timer is done and then calls the connected slot https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html#waitinginalocaleventloop