# QlineEdit selectAll doesn't work?

Tags: qt, qlineedit, selectall

I use folowing code. In it `lineEdit->selectAll()` works called by pushButton and **only** at first launch called by `eventFilter`. Although `label->setText` works all time propperly. Why?

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->lineEdit->selectAll();
}

bool Widget::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == ui->lineEdit && event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn )
    {
        ui->lineEdit->selectAll();
        ui->label->setText("Focused!");
        return false;
    }
    if (object == ui->lineEdit && event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut )
    {
        ui->label->setText("unFucused!");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

UPD: Did what **Ilya** recomended. Still have same problem.

```
void myLine::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
{
    setText("Focused!");
    selectAll();
}

void myLine::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
{
    setText("UnFocused!");
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the focusInEvent / focusOutEvent of `QWidget` ?

Comment: Is it (using the focusInEvent) possible if i created `QLineEdit` by designer?

Comment: I don't see why not ?

Comment: I should add this:`void lineedit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
{
    ui->lineEdit->selectAll();
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);
}` ? But where in code?

Comment: Yes, is it working ?

Comment: No, adding that code in widget.cpp makes warning `'lineedit' has not been declared`.

Comment: Ah OK, your question is "how do I subclass my lineEdit", is it ?

Comment: Rather "how do I subclass my lineEdit created by disigner?".

Comment: OK, I'll explain that option in an answer then

Comment: What happens if you do the select in the focusOut ?

Comment: `selectAll()` works normal in the focusOut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found answer here [Select text of QLineEdit on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434174/select-text-of-qlineedit-on-focus)

Instead  `ui->lineEdit->selectAll()` 
should use `QTimer::singleShot(0,ui->lineEdit,SLOT(selectAll()))`, 
because `mousePressEvent` trigers right after `focusInEvent` so text selected in `focusInEvent` unselects by `mousePressEvent`.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up things to me too.
Can I make any assumptions on the order of events triggering?

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering the question, but there's a more "standard" way of customizing these events.

- Create a QLineEdit subclass and define your own `focusInEvent` / `focusOutEvent` handlers.
- If you're using the UI Designer, promote your lineEdit to your subclass (right-click > "Promote to").

Answer (score -1):

Because you use eventFilter in a wrong way:

```
bool Widget::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == ui->lineEdit && event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn )
    {
        ui->lineEdit->selectAll();
        ui->label->setText("Focused!");
    }
    if (object == ui->lineEdit && event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut )
    {
        ui->label->setText("unFucused!");
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```